# Rails 3 - changing index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm using Rails 3 and have the feeling that the syntax for changing the route for the index (http://localhost:3000) is different than from the former versions.

I'd like to open the dynamic index page (index.html.erb) of the employees-controller (which can be right now opened with localhost:3000/employees) as the default page (localhost:3000). I thought it's quite easy, because in the routes it's written:

```
  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => "welcome#index"
```

So that's what I actually did: I deleted `public/index.html` and set `root :to => "employees#index"`. 
But when I open the server and open localhost:3000, it's still opening the **"welcome abroad!"**-page. Pretty weird!

So I googled the problem and found answers which said, I should write this into my routes-file:

`map.root :controller => 'employees', :action => 'index'`

Same here - I also still get the "welcome abroad!"-page and the rails-shell says "undefined local variable or method 'map'". (I think this is the old syntax for Rails 2...?)

`match "/" => "employees#index"` says `routing error: No route matches "/"`

So what did I do wrong? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like you *DIDN'T* delete `public/index.html` :)

Comment: Are you sure you restarted the server after deleting public/index.html?

Comment: HEH??? I don't get it, but now it worked. 
I surely (100%) deleted public/index.html. And I also restarted the server again. I even cleared my recycle bin... That didn't help after all. The only thing what helped, was **deleting also the image (public/images/rails.png) from the folder**. After that, I got my index page. Really weird... Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Why you use "map" in Rails 3? Should be:

```
   root :to => "employees#index"
```

Comment: yes, I realized that this is not the right method for Rails 3. I'm quite new to Rails and so I'm not used to the conventions, and googling the answer just confused me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is of cookies. please clear the cookies and the refresh the page.